# in sql how to arrange rows of data into colum using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Here i have a simple table i want to display all rows respected that year display in single column

```
Year  Month     Amt
1999   Jan       520
1999   Feb       100
199    Mar       200
2000   Jan       500
2000   Feb        200
```

I want to display these table as

```
Year   Jan     Feb     Mar   
1999    520    100      200  
2000    500    200      null
```

I had Written query as `invoice`  its my table name

```
   select
       [Jan] as January,
       [Feb] as Feburary,
       [March] as Feburary,
from(
select Year,month,amount from invoice)x

PIVOT(
sum(amount)
for month in([jan],[Feb],[March])

)p
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query? Add `[Year]` also in the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Try This Query**

```
create table #Invoice
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Year varchar(4),
    Month varchar(3),
    Amount int
)

insert into #Invoice (Year, Month, Amount) values ('1999','Jan',520),('1999','Feb',100),('1999','Mar',200),
('2000','Jan',500),('2000','Feb',200)

select Year, [Jan], [Feb],[Mar],[Grand Total]
from (
    select Year, Month, Amount
    from #Invoice
    Union all
    select Year, 'Grand Total', SUM(Amount)
    from #Invoice
    group by year
)dd
pivot (
    sum(Amount) for Month in ([Jan], [Feb],[Mar],[Grand Total])
) piv

drop table #Invoice
```

[image]

Comment: Add month name in pivot : pivot (
  sum(Amount) for Month in ([Jan], [Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun])
 ) piv

Comment: Which column do you want to sum? Is it Amount or something else? What is your requirement? Please clear it. as per question's required output, i have written correct query.

Comment: after march i need a column as Total and display Grand total  --Like in ur 1st column 1999  total is 820

Comment: Thanks a lot u Reduce my lot of pressure

Comment: may i know ur fb account

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `CTE`. You can't GROUP BY  `YEAR` within the PIVOT table operator, the `PIVOT` operator infers the grouped columns automatically. This seems to work

```
WITH Pivoted
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM table1
PIVOT 
( 
sum([Amt]) FOR [month] IN ( [jan],[Feb],[Mar])
) AS p
) 
SELECT 
    Year,
    sum([Jan]) as January,
    sum([Feb]) as Feburary,
    sum([Mar]) as March
FROM Pivoted
GROUP BY Year;
```

[REXTESTER DEMO](http://rextester.com/IIFD65610)